# XSL to FO and HTML entities

Tags: java, xslt, optimization, xsl-fo, html-encode

I'm developing a Java class that converts an HTML string  into a FO string via an XSLT document.

Then, the resulting FO string is processed by FOP to create a PDF file.

The problem is that when a special character is found by FOP, i get an error:

```
(e.g.) The entity "ldquo" was referenced, but not declared.
```

Now my solution is to replace all these special characters with their Unicode reference.

In this example, `"&ldquo;"` becomes `"&#8220;"`

Can I declare those entities in my XSLT file without doing zillions of StringUtils.replaceAll()?

Comment: Well how do you feed the HTML input to your XSLT? Either make sure it is well-formed XHTML where all entities referenced are declared properly in the DOCTYPE or use a HTML5 parser like http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/ instead of an XML parser.

Comment: Your situation is unclear.  You state "converts HTML ... via an XSLT document", yet XSLT cannot read an HTML file, it can only read an XML file.  If you were converting your HTML to XML, then you would have already solved this problem because the XML would be correct.  What file are you passing to the XSLT processor?  I tell my students that to process HTML information with XSLT I first use the W3C Tidy tool to convert it to XHTML and then invoke Saxon with an entity resolver for the W3C DTD fragment that resolves entities.

Comment: thanks G. Ken Holman. How do you invoke Saxon with an entity resolver?

Comment: I've tried to clean my html with JTidy and then use a custom EntityResolver with Saxon. I keep getting this error: "White spaces are required between publicId and systemId"

Comment: Solved using JTidy with setXmlOut(true). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Solved using JTidy with setXmlOut(true)